# connect a photo to a user for avatar

Tags: php

I can get photos to upload as a user,
 but I need to be able to pick that photo I just uploaded and display it as an avatar?
 the problem is all the photos from all the users go into the same public folder so not sure how to show only the photo that the user uploaded

I am using Laravel

here is my form:

```
              <h1>File Upload</h1>
                  <form class="picwid" action="{{ URL::to('../user/edituser') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label>Select image to upload:</label>
                      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
                  </form>
```

here is my function:

```
public function uploads(Request $request) {

     $users = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', auth()->id())->latest()->get(); 

        if(Input::hasFile('file')){

        $file = Input::file('file');
        $file->move('profilepics', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $myImage = '<img src="profilepics"/>' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

     }

     return view('edituser', compact(['baskets', 'myImage']));

 }
```

and here is my avatar output:

```
<div class="media-left">
    <img src="../profilepics/ty.jpg" class="media-object" style="width:60px">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what your actual question / issue is.

Comment: Just adding a questionmark to a sentence doesn't make it a good question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your `img` src must be dynamic (depends on the framework you use).

Comment: Rename the uploaded image to something like `user_id.jpg` and when you present it use `<img src="../profilepics/'. $user_id. '.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function uploads to:

```
 public function uploads() {

     $users = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', auth()->id())->latest()->get(); 

     $users_id = auth()->id();

        if(Input::hasFile('file')){

        $file = Input::file('file');
        $file->move("profilepics/ $users_id", $file->getClientOriginalName());       
        }

     return view('edituser', compact(['baskets', 'myImage', 'users_id']));

 }
```